# How to use activity as a navigator in compose

Tags: android, android-activity, android-navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I use the navigation of official example OwlApp as my main navigation system, and I want to achieve the camerax in my project. But there is no easy way to combine camera in compose, so I think if have a way to let a activity which have a camera screen act as a compose destination, then I can navigate it normally as the app does.

Comment: So you are looking for a way to start a new activity in a `Composable` function?

Comment: I tried to pass any activity related variable and function to compose to work around.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle this by passing a lambda into the composable function and implementing the logic outside of the composable function (inside your activity).

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var onCameraClick : () -> Unit

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            SampleTheme {
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    MainView(onCameraClick = onCameraClick)
                }
            }
        }

        onCameraClick = {
            // Camera logic inside activity scope.
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainView(onCameraClick : () -> Unit) {
    Button(onClick = onCameraClick) {
        Text(text = "Camera")
    }
}
```